# Python: Not able to call .csv rows for plot data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to collect x, y1 and y2 data into a .csv and then calling the .cvs to show a plot.
The .csv is made and populated just fine, but there's trouble getting the data plotted.

```
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#store .csv
filename = 'data'
filetime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
filetyp = '.csv'
filename = filename + filetime + filetyp

#x parameters
sample = .001
iterations = 1000

with open(filename,'w', newline= "") as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    w = csv.writer(f1)
    w.writerow(['time','CO','PV'])
    for i in range(iterations):
        x = i*sample
        y1 = 3
        y2 = 4
        w.writerow([x,y1,y2])
        time.sleep(sample)

time.sleep(2)

with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[1]))
        y1.append(float(row[1]))
        y2.append(float(row[1]))     

plt.plot(x,y1, label='Title')
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Title2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please be specific: what is the exact problem? "There's trouble" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Sorry.. 'float' object has no attribute 'append' at line 32.

Comment: Just not sure how to pull in that data...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=float+object+has+no+attribute+append

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.